# How can i moderate svg path command A(eliptical arc) value using d3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm a beginner in d3.js. When I'm trying to draw a group of arcs, there seems to be a narrow line between each arc. I set `.attr('stroke-width','0')`. But, it's not about the stroke. I inspect one of the arcs and the path data is

```
<path transform="rotate(-270)" class="node node--root" d="M5.640042262694442,44.64515565293754A45,45,0,0,0,8.432205445549114,44.20291745263034L7.905192605202295,41.44023511184094A42.1875,42.1875,0,0,1,5.28753962127604,41.85483342462894Z" fill="#FA6400C6" stroke="#FA6400C6" stroke-width="0"></path>
```

I temporarily edited above mentioned path command L value from `L7.905192605202295,41.44023511184094A42.1875,42.1875,0,0,1,5.28753962127604,41.85483342462894Z` to `L7.905192605202295,41.44023511184094A42.1875,42.1875,0,0,0,5.28753962127604,41.85483342462894Z`
then there is no line between arcs . How can I change this permanently to each path?

[Click here to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xalXV.jpg)
**My arc function is**

```
                    var arc=d3.arc()
                             .innerRadius(function (d) { return radiusScale(d.innerRad) })
                             .outerRadius(function (d) { return radiusScale(d.outerRad) })
                             .startAngle(function (d) { return -(d.startAngle*Math.PI/180)})
                             .endAngle(function (d) { return -(d.endAngle*Math.PI/180)});
                        group.selectAll("arc").data(dataset).enter().append("path").attr('transform','rotate(-270)')
                                    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                                    .on("mouseover", function(d){return tooltip.html("<p>Segment:<strong>"+d.seg+"</strong><br/>Color value:<strong>"+d.colorVal+"</strong><br/>Color code:<strong>"+d.color+"</strong><br/>Start Angle:<strong>"+d.startAngle+"</strong><br/>End Angle:<strong>"+d.endAngle+"</strong><br/>Outer Radius:<strong>"+d.outerRad+"</strong><br/>Inner Radius:<strong>"+d.innerRad+"</strong><br/><br/><input type='color' value='"+d.colorWithoutTransp+"' style='width:100%;height:30px;'/></p>").style("visibility", "visible");})
                                    .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
                                    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
                                    .attr("d",arc)
                                    .attr('fill',function(d){return d.color})
                                    .attr('stroke',function(d){return d.color})
                                    .attr('stroke-width','0');
```

Comment: d3.selectAll('path').remove()

Comment: @AnuragDas welcome to stack overflow. Right now it's hard to understand what's exactly your problem. You can create a running snippet (click the `<>` symbol in the top toolbar) to reproduce the problem, creating your arcs and those mysterious lines.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, could you please check the above code and image

Comment: @KEKUATAN,"d3.selectAll('path').remove()"   this code will remove all paths .I don't wanna remove the path. I have to fix the problem of a line bug that appear between arcs.

Comment: inspect all the line, make sure all the mysteries line have same class (node node--root), if ok then, you can remove the line by class, selectAll('.node--root').remove(), if not like that, is hard to find your problem, please learn more d3 or learn how to make good question in here. we can help but at least give us a proper question

Comment: How can i set **sweep-flag**  to zero for every angle?